# Escrever HTML em fontes JSF - Frameworks?

Tags: java, jsf

Vejo em vários exemplos de código as views usando aquelas tags [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp), o que eu acho muito feio e sujo.

Há algum framework web java que é usado em *app* corporativo e que possa me dar o html normal, sem aquelas tags feias, como `<h:form>` e outras?

Answer (score 1):

Se a versão do JSF for 1.2 ou maior, basta escrever o HTML normal sem problemas no seu fonte. A transformação é aplicada apenas nas tags JSF.

Se for a versão 1.1, use:

```
<f:verbatim><p>Meu HTML normal</p></f:verbatim>
```

Comment: Complementando a resposta do Cigano, com JSF 2.2 você pode usar HTML5 também.

Comment: @RodrigoSiejaBertin mas tem aquelas tags feias do jsp ?

Comment: @Rod Se não quiser usar os componentes do JSF, não. Mas não é do JSP o prefixo; ele serve para identificar que determinada tag pertence a determinada biblioteca (definida no início do documento - e se você definir no estilo Facelets, não pode usar tags JSP e vice-versa). As tag JSP são assim: <% algumcodigo(); %>

Comment: @Rod Dê uma olhada no framework Wicket da Apache também: http://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/guestbook.html

Comment: @RodrigoSiejaBertin e aquelas tags '<h:Input..' ?

Comment: @Rod Não tem como fugir dos prefixos porque são eles que definem qual componente é o quê. E no Wicket o prefixo não vai na tag, mas nos atributos. O JSF 2.2 suporta tags HTML5; quanto ao Wicket dar o mesmo suporte, aí eu já não sei, você tem que pesquisar.

Comment: @Rod O JSF 2.2 se comporta de forma semelhante ao Wicket nesse quesito. Particularmente, prefiro <h:head> a <head jsf:id="head">, que seria a utilização do HTML5 com JSF 2.2.

Comment: e por que não apenas <head ? rsrs

Comment: @Rod no seu caso, talvez o jeito seja continuar usando frameworks action based mesmo kkkkkk vida longa ao Struts 1 e ao SpringMVC kkkk (usa pelo menos um JSTL e tals, porque scriplet ninguém merece mais hehe)